# How Are Other Columns MySQL Aggregate with Other Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table like so:

```
Name   Type   Val
Mike   A      1
John   A      4
Jerry         6
```

(Notice that Jerry has an empty string for `Type`)

And I do a query like

```
Select sum(Val), Type from table
```

How does MySQL choose which `Type` to put in the one row result? If I wanted to return the "non blanked"

To give some context, the Type for every row in this table should actually be the same, but there used to be a bug where there are now some values that are blank. (Note that the sum should still include the blanks)

I know I can do this in two queries, and just `select Type from table where Type!=""` but I was curious if there was a trick to do it in that single query.

Comment: Not sure what platform your on, but i dont think the sql you've set is valid.  You'd need a `group by type` to make it compile.  In which case you can add a `where type != ''` to make a single query.

Comment: Except in (AFAIK) MySQL what you get is an error.

Comment: I'm using MySQL and SQLLite - I edited post to clarify

Answer (score 0):

This is valid SQL in MySQL. You are aggregating all rows to one row (by using the aggregate function SUM and having no GROUP BY clause).

Any value that is neither in a GROUP BY clause nor being aggregated is a random one. The type you get is just one of those types in the table; it could even be another one when you execute the same query again.

You can use `max(type)` or `min(type)` for instance to get the value you are after.

Comment: Interesting - is it truly random random?

Comment: Well, it is supposed to be a random match within the group. (As there is no group by and no where clause in your example it is a random value of all records.) I suppose MySQL just oicks the first or last value it sees, so it is not very likely that you will get different results when firing the same query twice, but you cannot rely on it.

Comment: Here is an example when to use this safely: `select o.id, o.order_date, sum(od.amount) from order o join order_details od  on od.order_id = o.id group by o.id`. You join order and order details here, thus getting the order multi-fold. Then you group by order. You simply group by order.id and pick a "random" order date. As this is the same date for all records in the group (it's the one date of the order), you don't need to put this in the GROUP BY clause or ridiculously pick max(o.order_date) or min(o.order_date) - as you would have to in most other dbms - you simply access the o.order_date.